# How to install Sikuli in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, sikuli

I want to automate a Windows app which will also become a mobile app. I am thinking of creating a test automation framework from scratch using IntelliJ.

Since the older tests are already written in Sikuli, I would like to keep them too. What are the steps for setting up Selenium and Sikuli in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you use Maven. In this case you just need to add next dependency to POM.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.999</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I keep getting this error even though I have added the dependency.Error:(5, 25) java: package org.sikuli.script does not exist .